# Creating a web2py form based on the currently authenticated user which populates a database table

Tags: web2py

I have a database table which references the web2py-supplied
`auth_user` table:

```
db.define_table('t_user_business',
    Field('f_user_id', type='reference auth_user',
          label=T('User Id')),
    Field('f_name', type='string',
          label=T('Name')),
    Field('f_link', type='string',
          label=T('Link')),
    Field('f_importance', type='integer',
          label=T('Importance')),
    auth.signature,
    format='%(f_user_id)s',
    migrate=settings.migrate)
```

I would like to design a page which has a form that lists all the
current entries in this table for the authenticated
user. E.g. something along the lines of

```
db.t_user_business.f_user_id==3
```

Where `3` is replaced with the `auth_user.id` value of the currently
logged in user.

Also, on the same page, I would like to have a form that allows the user to
enter a new record for this table and upon submission it commits this
validated record to the database.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Also, what do you mean you want the form to list the current entries -- do you want a select widget including these values, or something else?

Comment: @Anthony - I have tried the query and know that it returns the dataset I want to display in a non-editable tabular fashion. So no, I am not looking for a select widget, just a non-editable list of the records. Regarding the database query, I dont know what aspect of the incoming request to access to get the id of the currently authenticated user. And finally I do not know how to render a form that, upon submission, will a new value into `t_user_business` - the schema of which is defined in the question body.

Comment: @Anthony - the [smartgrid output](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview?search=smartgrid#Adding-grids) is perfect - table of data with headings. Except I don't want the "View/Edit/Delete" buttons that it has.

Answer (score 0):

When a user is logged in, the value of the user ID is in `auth.user_id`, so you can use that to set the default value of the `f_user_id` field:

```
Field('f_user_id', type='reference auth_user',
      default=auth.user_id, # Will be None if no logged in user.
      readable=False, writable=False, label=T('User Id'))
```

With the above default, whenever a `SQLFORM` form is submitted for this table, the value of `f_user_id` will automatically be set to the ID of the currently logged in user.

Note, the `readable` and `writable` attributes are set to `False`, so this field will not appear in forms. It will also not appear in the grid, but you can change that by changing the `readable` attribute before defining the grid:

```
db.t_user_business.f_user_id.readable = True
```

To display a grid of records in this table associated with the current user (without any view/edit/delete buttons), you can do:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.t_user_business.f_user_id == auth.user_id,
                    deletable=False, editable=False, details=False)
```